# Response of Requests made shown as empty in json report of newman

Tags: report, postman, response, newman

After running the collection using newman with json reporter, json file gets generated.

But for response portion it is [] i.e. empty, while it has different response related attributes with proper values (e.g. for responseTime, responseSize, etc).

So how can I get the response body/data in this json reporter.

As per my actual requirement, I need to record response for each request made in either json or excel/csv format file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was not able to solve this problem directly, I used Newman as a javascript library and recorded the request and response in separate text files.

The files generated will have file names like request1, request2 and so on for request files; and similar behavior will be for response files and their names for every execution.

Below is the code for the above mentioned solution:

```
const newman = require('newman'),
      fs = require('fs');
var rq = 1;
var rs = 1;

newman.run({
    collection: require('./ABC.postman_collection.json'),
    environment: require('./XYZ.postman_environment.json'),
    iterationData: './DataSet.csv',
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('beforeRequest', function (error, args) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        fs.writeFile('request' + rq++ + '.txt', args.request.body.raw, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });    
    }
}).on('request', function (error, args) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        fs.writeFile('response' + rs++ + '.txt', args.response.stream, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });        
    }
});
```